# How to open an external application only for Activity XAMLs, not for WPF XAMLs, in VisualStudio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013, workflow-foundation-4

I have a C# solution with lots of XAML files. Some of them are WF4 activities, some are WPF files (MainWindow.xaml etc).

When I doubleclick on a XAML file in SolutionExplorer, I would **like** to have an external application open for all activities (we have a rehosted Activity Designer executable). But if I configure this application for XAML files as default, VisualStudio of course launches it for WPF XAMLs as well. For WPF files, I want to keep the default behaviour (opening in the WPF designer inside VS2013)

So there must be a way to distinguish the default open action by file content, not only by file extension. Is this possible in any way with VS2013? Maybe not natively, but with an extension...?

Comment: Well, not **exactly** what I wanted to hear... :(

Comment: They have different build actions, but you can't AFAICT configure documents by build type (wpf is Page, I forget what activities are).  An extension could figure that out, if you wanted to develop one...

Answer (score 0):

You could [validate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3cd94b30-2956-4a03-a7d6-508cddb59152/how-we-can-validate-workflow-xaml-file?forum=wfprerelease) if the XAML file is a Workflow XAML file before opening it with a rehosted workflow designee. Otherwise open with a regular standalone XAML designer.

Comment: Yes, that would work if I had an external WPF XAML designer, but with WPF files I would like to stay inside VS2013 :(

Comment: Please refer to below link about "Visual Studio Editor Choosing System" on how VS opens various XAML files with different Editor. Looks like it only supports in-process Editors in the system. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2010/05/02/visual-studio-editor-choosing-system.aspx